# get wordpress page content and limit the word

Tags: wordpress

I have a code that can get page content:

```
<?php
$page = get_page_by_title( 'page-name' );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
echo $content;
?>
```

This is working code with one problem I have no idea how I can limit the word. I only want to display 20 word from that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string_limit_words()` is neither a standard PHP or WordPress function therefore the solution isn't widely applicable. Anybody wishing to limit the text length in the manner described would have to write their own `string_limit_words()` function or track down the same code you're using.

My suggestion would be to use `wp_trim_words()` which is a function built into WordPress for this exact purpose.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words

Example:

```
<?php
$page = get_page_by_title( 'page-name' );
$trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $page->post_content, 20, '' );
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $trimmed_content );
```

Answer (score 0):

for those who encounter with same trouble this is how I get the working one..

```
<?php
$page = get_page_by_title( 'about us' );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
echo string_limit_words($content,20);
?>
```

hope this help thank's